# How do I make a glass texture with an outline?

Tags: glass, outliner

I am using cycles as my output for my creation, and currently, I am working on trying to make a glass ball with a white outline. I already separately tested the methods, however, when I try to put them together (by changing the solid material into a transparent, glass material), the outline will fill the entire shape instead of creating just an outline.

If there is a way to make glass with a real-time outline, please let me know! Thanks

The picture with the color wheel is the picture for the setup of the outline. For the outline, I used an addon called "Outline Helper" since many of the other ways to make outlines crashed Blender for me.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of your node set up

Comment: I'm so sorry I didn't see that you commented! I updated it now, but I am really new to this so I'm not sure if this was what you asked for

Comment: there still arent any pictures in your post. regardless, one easy way to get a sort of outline is with the Fresnel texture. if you run it through a color ramp and then use that as the factor in a mix shader, you can get a decent outline.

Comment: Sorry I thought I did but thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To illustrate the suggested solution using Fresnel.

1. Combine a *Glass shader* (for glass) and an *Emission shader* (for the outline)
2. Add *Fresnel input* to drive the visibility. Change IOR to control the line thickness.
3. Use *Colorramp*  set to *Constant* for sharp outline edge

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: Happy to help :). Good luck with your project.